# How to run Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel webserver to different port for localhost machine

Tags: asp.net, deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC 5 project.

For debugging, I need to launch **`Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`** web server on port 80.

But when I'm publishing this website to Azure, it does't work (IT requires to change port to 8000).

[image: project.json configuration]

How to configure different ports in **`project.json`** for debug and release modes?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different command for debugging:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "web-debug": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://localhost:8000"
}
```

Then launch `web-debug` to debug locally (in Visual Studio, you can change the default command in project properties).

Comment: It works grate! I've just added `environmentVariables` in `launchSettings.json`